# Why do I get a foreach compiler error even though Iterable is implemented?

Tags: java, design-patterns, foreach, iterator, iterable

I'm trying to learn different design patterns in OOP and the current one I'm learning is iterator pattern. Therefore I have made two own interfaces (Iterable and Iterator).

I'm trying to iterate over `List<Person> friends`. But the row: `for (Person p : p1)` gives the following compiler error:

```
foreach not applicable to type 'com.company.Person'
```

Which to me makes no sense since I've implemented Iterable and overrided the iterator() method as far as I can see.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Here is my code:

Main class:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Erik");
    p1.addFriend("Lars");
    p1.addFriend("Jenny");
    p1.addFriend("Janne");


    for (Person p : p1) {
        System.out.println(p.name);
    }
```

Iterator:

```
public interface Iterator<T> {

    boolean hasNext();

    T next();

    void remove();
}
```

Iterable:

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

Person:

```
public class Person implements Iterable<Person>{
    private List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    int index = 0;
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addFriend(String name){
        friends.add(new Person(name));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Person> iterator(){
        return new Iterator<Person>() {
            //int index = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                System.out.println(index);
                return index < friends.size();

            }    

            @Override
            public Person next() {
                if(hasNext()){
                    return friends.get(index++);
                }
                else{
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void remove() {
                if(index<=0) {
                    friends.remove(index--);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you created your own `Iterable<...>` interface? foreach will only work with `java.lang.Iterable`.

Comment: Also, a `Person` is not iterable.  A *collection* of `Person` is.  If you already have a collection of  `Person` (as it seems you do), then you should already be able to iterate over that collection.

Comment: In other words, it should be `for (Person p : friends) { // do something with p }`, read as "For each `Person p` in your `friends` collection, do something with `p`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have defined your own `Iterator` and `Iterable` interfaces.  That's not how the foreach loop works in Java.

For a class to be a viable target for a foreach loop, it must implement the built-in `Iterable`, seen at [`java.lang.Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).  Remove your own `Iterator` and `Iterable` interfaces, and implement the built-in `Iterable` (and use the built-in `Iterator` as well).

Additionally, as far as your semantics goes, it may not make much sense to have the `Person` class be `Iterable`.  The collection of the person's friends should be the `Iterable`.  Instead, you may want to expose the collection of friends via a `getFriends()` method that would return an unmodifiable view of that list (`Collections.unmodifiableList(friends)`).  The list is already `Iterable`, saving you the need to implement it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I remembered my teacher doing it that way, that's why I specifically tried to impement my own written interfaces. After double checking his lectures again, it seems like he did in fact use the existing interfaces. I think he made his own classes for some kind of educational purposes and then went back to the existing ones.

Smart tips about getting the unmodifiableList. I will keep it in mind. This example just needed a class that implemented Iterable in order to test how it works.